# Webpack asset size limit

Tags: javascript, performance, webpack

I have built a react app, everything works fine but I keep getting this Warning saying `WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB)`but my bundle is only 120kib. Any knows why?

```
WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
    Entrypoints:
      main (120 KiB)
          main.js
```

Comment: There is a list of assets below the entrypoint, it might have emitted some other assets. Post the entire message

Comment: Just added the message.

Comment: should I just ignore it ?

Comment: This looks like a bug... Try to create a simple example and report as an issue